# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un menú con el metodo post?

Tags: php

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se presione cambie los resultados y que me muestre la categoría que quiero.

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
<section id="menu">
            <div class="menua">
                <a <?php $CategoriGet = 'todo'; ?> >Todo</a>
            </div>
            <div class="menua"><button onclick="<?php $CategoriGet = "html"; ?>">Html</button></div>
            <div class="menua"><button onclick="<?php $CategoriGet = "php"; ?>">Php</button></div>
            <div class="menua"><a href="">Mysql</a></div>
            <div class="menua"><a href="">JavaScript</a></div>
            <div class="menua"><a href="">css</a></div>
        </section>
        <hr>
        <section id="mainResultado">
            <article class="resultadoart">
                <?php
                       // Instancia de la conexión con los datos requeridos
if($CategoriGet = "todo"){

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=help_programing', 'root', '');
                    $likeparametro= "%$BusquedaGet%";
                    $stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites 
                                          WHERE titulo LIKE ? ORDER BY ID DESC");
                    //Ejecutamos la consulta , pasamos el parámetro para el like, 
                    //que será una variable que ya se construyó anteriormente
                    $stmt->execute([$likeparametro]);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();//Obtenemos los resultados
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.

    if ($data){ //Data será FALSE o NULL si no se encuentran datos o si la consulta falla
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.
        foreach($data as $row) {
                ?>
        <a class="contresult" href="?view=pagew&id=<?php echo $row['viewPage']; ?>&cateinfo=<?php echo $row['categoria']; ?>">
            <div class="conResult">
                <div class="titulocon">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="contcon">
                    <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
                }}else{
        ?>
            <h1>Lo sentimos pero la página "<?php echo $BusquedaGet; ?>" no existe.</h1>
            <br>
            <h2>Porfavor escriba bien o especifique bien en que lenguaje esta buscando.</h2>
        <?php
            }}

elseif($CategoriGet = "php"){

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=help_programing', 'root', '');
                    $likeparametro= "%$BusquedaGet%";
                    $stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites 
                                          WHERE titulo LIKE ? AND categoria = 2 ORDER BY ID DESC");
                    //Ejecutamos la consulta , pasamos el parámetro para el like, 
                    //que será una variable que ya se construyó anteriormente
                    $stmt->execute([$likeparametro]);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();//Obtenemos los resultados
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.

    if ($data){ //Data será FALSE o NULL si no se encuentran datos o si la consulta falla
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.
        foreach($data as $row) {
                ?>
        <a class="contresult" href="?view=pagew&id=<?php echo $row['viewPage']; ?>&cateinfo=<?php echo $row['categoria']; ?>">
            <div class="conResult">
                <div class="titulocon">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="contcon">
                    <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
                }}else{
        ?>
            <h1>Lo sentimos pero la página "<?php echo $BusquedaGet; ?>" no existe.</h1>
            <br>
            <h2>Porfavor escriba bien o especifique bien en que lenguaje esta buscando.</h2>
        <?php
            }}
        ?>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema o error presenta el código actualmente?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el mismo problema qué tu otra pregunta: [¿Por qué entra al if?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128132/por-qu%C3%A9-entra-al-if)

Hay 2 errores en tu código

1. Las condiciones if estas asignando valor con el operador =, en vez de comparar valores con el operador ==.
2. Las ejecuciones de tus consultas con PDO las ejecutas 2 veces, debería de ser una.