# ¿Por qué entra al if?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Como ven estoy haciendo `if` para que no salgan los otros, pero siempre aparecen, y no se que hacer.

Aquí esta mi código:

```
<?php
if($CategoriGet = "1"){
           // Instancia de la conexión con los datos requeridos
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=help_programing', 'root', '');
                    $likeparametro= "%$BusquedaGet%";
                    $stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites 
                                          WHERE titulo LIKE ? AND categoria = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC");
                    //Ejecutamos la consulta , pasamos el parámetro para el like, 
                    //que será una variable que ya se construyó anteriormente
                    $stmt->execute([$likeparametro]);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();//Obtenemos los resultados
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.
    if ($data){ //Data será FALSE o NULL si no se encuentran datos o si la consulta falla
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.
        foreach($data as $row) {
                ?>
        <a class="contresult" href="?view=pagew&id=<?php echo $row['viewPage']; ?>&cateinfo=<?php echo $row['categoria']; ?>">
            <div class="conResult">
                <div class="titulocon">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="contcon">
                    <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
                }}else{
        ?>
            <h1>Lo sentimos pero las páginas referidas a "<?php echo $BusquedaGet; ?>" no existen.</h1>
            <br>
            <h2>Porfavor escriba bien o especifique bien en que lenguaje esta buscando.</h2>
        <?php
            }} else{
    ?>
            <h1>Lo sentimos pero los rexsultados en HTML no existen.</h1>
            <br>
            <h2>Porfavor escriba bien o especifique bien en que lenguaje esta buscando.</h2>
        <?php
    }
if($_GET['categoria'] = "2"){
           // Instancia de la conexión con los datos requeridos
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=help_programing', 'root', '');
                    $likeparametro= "%$BusquedaGet%";
                    $stmt  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *FROM pageswebsites 
                                          WHERE titulo LIKE ? AND categoria = 2 ORDER BY ID DESC");
                    //Ejecutamos la consulta , pasamos el parámetro para el like, 
                    //que será una variable que ya se construyó anteriormente
                    $stmt->execute([$likeparametro]);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $data = $stmt->fetchAll();//Obtenemos los resultados
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.
    if ($data){ //Data será FALSE o NULL si no se encuentran datos o si la consulta falla
                    //Iteramos sobre estos resultados.
        foreach($data as $row) {
                ?>
        <a class="contresult" href="?view=pagew&id=<?php echo $row['viewPage']; ?>&cateinfo=<?php echo $row['categoria']; ?>">
            <div class="conResult">
                <div class="titulocon">
                    <h2><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></h2>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="contcon">
                    <p><?php echo $row['content']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
                }}else{
        ?>
            <h1>Lo sentimos pero las páginas referidas a "<?php echo $BusquedaGet; ?>" no existen.</h1>
            <br>
            <h2>Porfavor escriba bien o especifique bien en que lenguaje esta buscando.</h2>
        <?php
            }} else{
        ?>
            <h1>Lo sentimos pero los rexsultados en PHP no existen.</h1>
            <br>
            <h2>Porfavor escriba bien o especifique bien en que lenguaje esta buscando.</h2>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay 2 errores en tu código

1. Las condiciones `if` estas asignando valor con el operador `=`, en vez de comparar valores con el operador `==`.
2. Las ejecuciones de tus consultas con **PDO** las ejecutas 2 veces, debería de ser una.